# PHP calculator with its result on a different html page

Tags: php, html

Lately I have been designing and coding a website for one of my clients. One of the functions he needs is a calculator in PHP. The problem is, I can get the calculator up and running and I could probably make the calculator in jQuery as well, but he wants the result of the calculation on the next page. The calculator should be able to do simple calculations that include: multiplication, dividing, subtracting and adding. So far I have styled up and made the HTML structure of the calculator, but when it comes to the PHP code... I have no clue. So is there anyone here that has any experience of coding a calculator but showing its result in on a different page?

**Preferably, you could use the HTML structure I have built:**

```
<input type="text" title="result" class="input-result" name="result" readonly="readonly" value=""/>
<div class="row-container">
    <ul class="row1-ul">
        <li class="row1 calc-1 numbers">1</li>
        <li class="row1 calc-2 numbers">2</li>
        <li class="row1 calc-3 numbers">3</li>
        <li class="row1 calc-x">X</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="row2-ul">
        <li class="row2 calc-4 numbers">4</li>
        <li class="row2 calc-5 numbers">5</li>
        <li class="row2 calc-6 numbers">6</li>
        <li class="row2 calc-/">/</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="row3-ul">
        <li class="row3 calc-7 numbers">7</li>
        <li class="row3 calc-8 numbers">8</li>
        <li class="row3 calc-9 numbers">9</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="row4-ul">
        <li class="row4 calc-0 numbers">0</li>
        <li class="row4 calc-+">+</li>
        <li class="row4 calc--">-</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="column-last calc-=">=</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any experience with PHP? Or is there a specific task which you are having problems finding a solution for? In that case your existing PHP code would be useful.

Comment: Telling us to just do this code for you isn't effective - Can you post what PHP you've tried?

Comment: Honestly, I have no specific experience in PHP apart from some Wordpress codex. The problem is, I could probably make the calculator in jQuery; but the problem I am facing here is that the client want the result of the calculation made on that page display on another .html page. For example: the calculator is on calculator.html and the result when the = button is pressed has to be shown on result.php. Hope this helped :)

Comment: I guess I could find a simply PHP calculator script, but do you guys know how to display the result on an other page then?

Comment: If this is for a client, it would suggest you're getting paid for it... so we should do this for you for free?

Comment: Yeah just store it in a session variable or POST it or something?

Comment: Well Marc, I guess that would be fair if you had to do the job, but since I can probably do it myself as well with some suggestions... I don't know ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you could probably do it in jQuery, that would be the best idea. Wrap the whole calculator in something like this

```
<form action='result.php' method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="finalresult">
```

and have a button enter the final result into that hidden input before performing `form.submit()` (which is what an input of type submit does by standard). Your PHP script in "result.php" will be able to access the result as `$_POST['finalresult']`. Remember this comes from a script so it's user input and can potentially be anything they are trying to do to wreck your scripts though.

Edit: `$_POST['finalresult']` will be a variable which you can use in the PHP script of results.php. Enter the result into the input using `.val(num)` and in results.php do something like `var $calc_result = (float) $_POST['finalresult'];` to avoid users fiddling around.

You will need at least the basics of PHP so I suggest you have a read through the w3 PHP tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp (also see the $_POST one in the side bar).

Comment: Ow great, this probably what I am just going to do then. But, one question: is result.php only going to be containing $_POST['finalresult'] and that will make sure the result is of the jQuery calculation is on that page? Thanks for your time, thanks :)